# Android TextView center text

Tags: android, textview, center

This will allow to make textview horizontally centered.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/footer_text" />
```

Comment: Is this a question or an order? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code like this:

```
<TextView  
android:id="@+id/footer_text"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="@string/footer_text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something that is confused often when starting android. `layout_gravity` determines how the view is aligned within the parent. `gravity` centers the contents of the view within the view container. So layout_gravity would center your view in your layout, while gravity would center your text in it's view.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footer_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/footer_text"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

And, assuming  that you want your footer to stretch the width of the layout you could do this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footer_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/footer_text"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Just to handle things a little better, but again that is only if your view stretches the entire layout width.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it for example into a LinearLayout like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/footer_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Centered text example" />

</LinearLayout>
```